# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer un objeto dentro de otro?

Tags: json, reactjs, webservice, object, react-hooks

Tengo el siguiente **json** que esta hecho en node, el **endpoint** lo estoy consumiendo de una unión de dos tablas, pero no sé como puedo acceder al **campo teacher**:

[image: json]

He intentado esto, pero me sale undefined:

[image: codigo]

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Hay dos cosas que veo raras. ¿Por qué usas el método `map` en el objeto `teacher`, si no es un *array*? Al argumento que recibes de la *callback* de `map`, ¿por qué le llamas `item`, también? ¿No puede haber ambigüedad entre el `item` de `entries` y el `item` del `map`?

Comment: JesusPonce puedes poner tu codigo? no nos ayuda imagenes para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 2):

Debes hacer algo asi:

```
const objeto = {
  id: 81,
  day: 8,
  teacher: {
    nombre:"Yisus",
    status:true,
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{objeto.teacher.nombre}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

El problema está en:

```
{item.teacher.map(item=>(<span>{item.names}</span>))}
```

teacher es un objeto, y por lo tanto ese item seria "id", "names", "last_names"... En tu codigo lo que estas haciendo realmente es:

```
item.teacher.id.names
```

Es por ello por lo que te da undefined. En tu ejemplo seria entonces:

```
<div>
  {
    entries.map((item) => (
      <p key={item.id}>
        {item.hour}
        <span>{item.teacher.names}</span>
      </p>
    )
  }
</div>
```

Por ultimo decirte que la próxima vez pongas el codigo escrito en vez de con foto

Answer (score 0):

El API lo hice con sequelize me cambie a mongodb y ya no me trae esos problemas, gracias!!!

Comment: Algún detalle particular del cambio que mencionas, que creas conveniente incluir? Pues, para los que en el futuro pasen por el mismo problema.  Algo de la implementación del API que mencionas, etc?